# Creating new row for each year in a date range in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, range

I have a dataframe where each row has a range of years. This is the code to build it.

```
original = pd.DataFrame({'City': ['Paris','Rome','New York', 'Tokyo'], 'Color': ['red', 'orange', 'blue', 'purple'], 'Years': ['2010-2012', '2019-2020', '2015-2018', '2002-2003']})
```

The table looks something like this.

```
City    Color   Years
Paris     red       2010-2012
Rome      orange    2019-2020
New York  blue      2015-2018
Tokyo     purple    2002-2003
```

I want to create a new row for each year in the range of 'Years'. The dataframe should look like this.

```
City    Color   Years
Paris     red       2010
Paris     red       2011
...
New York  blue      2018
Tokyo     purple    2002
Tokyo     purple    2003
```

This is the code I'm using right now. I'm trying to add a new row for each year, but it only returns an empty dataframe, and I'm not sure why.

```
df_empty = pd.DataFrame({'City': [], 'Color': [], 'Years': []})

for index, row in original.iterrows():
    dates = [int(s) for s in row['Years'].split("-") if s.isdigit()]
    for i in range(dates[0],dates[1] + 1):
        newrow = row
        newrow.append(pd.Series([str(i)]))
        df_empty.add(newrow)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Idea is [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) columns to new `DataFrame`, so possible repeat index values by difference by years. Also is used [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for add all ranges of years per index values:

```
df = original['Years'].str.split('-', expand=True).astype(int)
original['Years'] = df[0]
df = original.loc[original.index.repeat(df[1] - df[0] + 1)]
df['Years'] += df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
        City   Color  Years
0      Paris     red   2010
1      Paris     red   2011
2      Paris     red   2012
3       Rome  orange   2019
4       Rome  orange   2020
5   New York    blue   2015
6   New York    blue   2016
7   New York    blue   2017
8   New York    blue   2018
9      Tokyo  purple   2002
10     Tokyo  purple   2003
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and list comprehension for ranges first `4` and last `4` characters for years:

```
original['Years'] = [[y for y in range(int(x[:4]), int(x[-4:]) + 1)] 
                        for x in original['Years']]

original = original.explode('Years').reset_index(drop=True)
print (original)
        City   Color Years
0      Paris     red  2010
1      Paris     red  2011
2      Paris     red  2012
3       Rome  orange  2019
4       Rome  orange  2020
5   New York    blue  2015
6   New York    blue  2016
7   New York    blue  2017
8   New York    blue  2018
9      Tokyo  purple  2002
10     Tokyo  purple  2003
```